# Как получить только числа, исключая слова в которых есть цифры?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Паттерн: `/( |-)?(\d*\.|\d*\,)?\d+/g` - получаем совпадения положительных и отрицательных целых и десятичных цифр.

Но как исключить совпадения со строками типа:

```
String1234567890 или String1234567890String или 1234567890String
```

Comment: Уточните язык программирования.

Comment: но у вас все числа содержат слово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно обозначить границы слова с помощью `\b`:

```
/\b( |-)?(\d*\.|\d*\,)?\d+\b/g
```

[Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/n8Y8cd/1)

**Обновление:**

В первой регулярке была ошибка: я забыл флаг `u`. Заодно упростил выражение:

```
/\b-?\d*[.,]?\d+\b/gu
```

[Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/n8Y8cd/3)

**Обновление 2:**

Во второй регулярке была ошибка: не учитывался случай, когда дефис и цифры в середине слова. Исправляю ошибку:

```
/(^|\s)\b-?\d*[.,]?\d+\b/gu
```

[Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/n8Y8cd/4/)

Comment: Посмотрите на это https://regex101.com/r/n8Y8cd/2

Comment: @Visman, да, я сначала не заметил, что русские слова не учитываются  в этом случае. Спасибо, исправлять начал сразу.

Comment: Я не про русские слова :) Я про границу слова при минусе ;)

Comment: @Visman, по-моему, это нормально :)

Comment: Эм.. По второй регулярке нельзя писать `2.`

Comment: @Qwertiy, а зачем это нужно?

Comment: @Visman, понял и исправил ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b-?\d+[.,]?\d*\b/g
```

Если нужно разрешить форму `.2`, то так:

```
/\b-?(\d+[.,]?\d*|[.,]\d+)\b/g
```